# visual studio 2010 intellisense won't auto-pop after period

Tags: visual-studio-2010, settings, intellisense

I can't get VS2010 to auto-pop after i type a period.

I'm programming in C#, and i've tried playing with the settings under *Tools > TextEditor > C# > Intellisense*, with no luck.

I've also tried 100 different ways to google it with no luck.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Verify that you have *Tools > Options > Text Editor > C#* --> *`Auto list members`* checked.

Comment: That did it.  Setting should have been listed in under intellisense in-addition/instead, i would think.

Answer (score 1):

Does ctrl-space force it to appear?

Also, If you haven't already, try resetting your IDE back to default and uninstalling/disabling extensions

I'm assuming you're using VS2010 RTM not a Beta or RC? The Beta an RC had problems with intellisense

Comment: Thanks.  That set me down the right path.  Had to google resetting, which didn't work, but led me to importing.

It is RTM and ctrl-space works.

Comment: I imported from my vs2008 settings and it worked.  Looking at the intellisense settings nothing has changed.  Looks like it was probably Autolist Members that Agent mentioned, but either way i'm much happier with life.